# Regexp which matches at least two different blacklisted word

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

This is a follow-up to [Regular expression which matches at least two words from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172433/regular-expression-which-matches-at-least-two-words-from-a-list):

How do I write a regexp which would match at least two *different* words from a list?

E.g., given the list `"foo"`, `"bar"`, `"baz"`, I would like the regexp to match `"foo..bar"` but not `"foo..foo"` and `"z baz "`.

Just like in the original question, I would like to avoid repeating the word list in the regexp (what if my blacklist has length of 30 instead of 3 as in the example?)

Comment: Is this a test for students?

Comment: @sln: no; alas, I am neither a student nor a teacher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the regex engine you use supports it, you can do it with a negative lookahead and a backreference:

```
(foo|bar|baz).*(?!\1)(foo|bar|baz)
```

`(?!\1)` means "not followed by the one in the first capturing group".

To not repeat twice the list a pcre regex engine offer different syntax:

```
(foo|bar|baz).*(?!\1)(?1)

(foo|bar|baz).*(?!\g{1})\g<1>

(?<list>foo|bar|baz).*(?!\g{list})\g<list>

(?(DEFINE)(?<list>foo|bar|baz))(\g<list>).*(?!\1)\g<list>
```

with Ruby:

```
(foo|bar|baz).*(?!\k<1>)\g<1>

(?<list>foo|bar|baz).*(?!\k<list>)\g<list>

(?<list>foo|bar|baz){0}\g<list>.*(?!\k<list>)\g<list>
```

But if the regex engine doesn't have a feature to reuse a subpattern, you can try this pattern *(works with pcre, Python re module, Java, .NET, Ruby but not with Javascript nor XRegExp)*:

```
(?:(?!\1)(foo|bar|baz).*){2}
```

Explanation:

At the begining (the first time) the capturing group is not defined and the backreference `\1` too. The regex engine ignores the lookahead condition *(note that this means that the regex engine does not consider `(?!\1)` as `(?!)`, but choose to skip the test!)*. Then the first word in the list is captured and the second time the backreference `\1` is now defined and the lookahead makes its job.

For R language, you can make it work using the param `perl=TRUE` and escaping the backslash (as in Java):

```
(?:(?!\\1)(foo|bar|baz).*){2}
```

Comment: balibaliba hey hey hey.

Comment: this repeats the word list twice - can this be avoided?

Comment: @sds: if the regex engine have this feature, you can write: `(foo|bar|baz).*(?!\1)(?1)` or with oniguruma syntax: `(?<w>foo|bar|baz).*(?!\g{w})\g<w>`

Comment: `R` says: `invalid regular expression '(?:(?!\1)(foo|bar|baz).*){2}', reason 'Invalid regexp'`, it expects `POSIX 1003.2 extended regular expressions`

Comment: @sds: see my edit. Note that the language-agnostic tag is rarely appropriate for regexes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! you have been most helpful!